# How do I stop py2neo watch()?

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I run this earlier in the code

`watch("httpstream")`

Subsequently, any `py2neo` commands that triggers HTTP traffic will result in verbose logging. How can I stop the effect of `watch()` logging without creating a new `Graph` instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the logging level to a higher value, for example

```
import logging

logging.getLogger("httpstream").setLevel(Logging.WARNING)
```

### Get Logger Information

You can enumerate a list of all available loggers

`print logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict.keys()`

Then, you can use either

`logging.getLogger("httpstream").getEffectiveLevel()`

or

`logging.getLogger("httpstream").isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG)`

to get the logging level.

Answer (score 4):

You don't. That is, I've not written a way to do that.

The watch function is intended only as a debugging utility for an interactive console session. You shouldn't need to use it in an application.